# React Hook "useCustomHook" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got error when i want to set if in customHook
Code

After this i got error ->

```
React Hook "" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render
```

Problem is if statment when call this work good ( without if )  ->

```
 const =(,());
```

I wan't to load useDataForm ( custom hook ) if **dataValid**   not valid and filled.

Comment: could you share more code, so that we can give a more adapted solution ? Ideally the code or the source of the custom hook, and the component where it is used; that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As per React documentation, [you cannot call hooks conditionally](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation) is explained in depth why.

When the need to call a hook conditionally arises, you could opt for two soutions :

1. Either you  call `useDataForm` and then you use `contactForm` only if `dataValid` is `true`

```
const contactForm = useDataForm(onSubmit, modelToForm(dataValid));
if (dataValid) {
    // do what you need to do with dataValid
}
// or 
return <Child data={dataValid ? contactForm : otherData} />
```

2. Either you move the hook in a separate component and render said component only if `dataValid` is true
3. Either, depending on the hook, you can pass the arguments conditionally. e.g. in your exemple:

```
const contactForm = useDataForm(onSubmit, dataValid   ? modelToForm(dataValid) : fallbackArg);
```

### Edit:

The canary version of React introduces `use`, a new hook that will likely become a standard feature in the React 19 version. This hook supersedes the rule that hooks cannot be called conditionally or within loops. You may find a way to use this hook to solve your conundrum with the custom hook.
However, it's important to note that the other rules of hooks remain valid. Specifically, hooks must still be called at the top level of components or other hooks.

Comment: I got error in modelToForm data when dataValid is not valid........ I can't props data to modelToForm if dataValid is not valid..

Comment: @MichaelDawalalt Can you please share more code  in your question? Like the whole component; it'd be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: Maybe something like `const contactForm = useDataForm(onSubmit, dataValid 
 ? modelToForm(dataValid) : fallbackArg);` would work, if the problem comes from `modelToForm` . But again, it'll be easier if we could see more code, and the hook's code as well if possible

Answer (score 2):

**We can’t call Hooks inside of conditionals,** loops, or nested functions in order to ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. The order is important for how React associates Hook calls with components.

Resource: [https://www.benmvp.com/blog/conditional-react-hooks/#:~:text=We%20can%27t%20call%20Hooks,associates%20Hook%20calls%20with%20components](https://www.benmvp.com/blog/conditional-react-hooks/#:%7E:text=We%20can%27t%20call%20Hooks,associates%20Hook%20calls%20with%20components).

You can check this resource maybe it can be helpful

Comment: I read but again i don't have a solution how to solve my problem

Comment: I've never faced with this error before. I just know that we can not use in conditionals. Sorry if it is not helpful.